$\exists k\in [0,1),\;\forall x>0,\;x|f'(x)|\leq k f(x)$. Prove that $f$ has a unique fixed point.

Let $X=(0,+\infty), f \in C^1(X)$. Suppose there exists $k\in [0,1): x|f'(x)|\leq k f(x) $ for all $x \in X$.
Prove that $f$ has unique fixed point.

I proved that the function $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ decrease and tried using intermediate value theorem, but can proof only $\frac{f(x_0)}{x_0}=x_0$. Also I thought about Lagrange theorem, but I don't know where I can use it.
Any hints are welcome!

If $f(x)/x$ is a decreasing function, how can it take the value $1$ at two different points?

@TedShifrin More likely, the issue is showing it equals $1$ at some point.

Ah, that part didn't even occur to me. The question indeed needs to be made explicit. That's one of the problem with just cutting and pasting questions.

Hint: Use an absurd reasoning. Suppose $f$ does not have one fixed point. Can you prove that $f$ must have at least one fixed point? So suppose $f$ has at least two fixed points and call two of them a and b and suppose a<b. Consider the subdominion [a,b]. Can you use Lagrange theorem in a way you obtain the contradiction? Can you use it to prove that atleast one point have $f^{'}(c)=1$.

There seems to be some assumption missing, at the moment $f(x)\equiv0$ is a counterexample.

Maybe the question was at most one fixed point?

@leoli1: Good catch – I had missed that initially. As the answers show it suffices to assume that $f(x) > 0$ for some $x > 0$ to make the statement true.

It can be proved that $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$ provided $f$ is not zero identically. I have included that in my answer.

As mentioned in a comment, the statement is wrong if $f$ is identically zero. Therefore we assume that $f(c) > 0$ for some $c > 0$.
The solution of the differential equation $x f'(x) = k f(x)$ is the function $x \mapsto x^k$, this suggests to consider $x^{-k}f(x)$. We have
$$
 (x^{-k} f(x))' = x^{-k} f'(x)-k x^{-k-1}f(x) = x^{-k-1}(x f'(x) - kf(x)) \le 0
$$
so that $x^{-k}f(x)$ is (weakly) decreasing.
First we show that $f$ has a fixed point. Consider the function
$$
g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x} = \frac{x^{-k}f(x)}{x^{1-k}} \, .
$$
For $0 < x < c$ is
$$
 g(x) \ge \frac{c^{-k}f(c)}{x^{1-k}} \implies \lim_{x \to 0^+} g(x) = +\infty \, ,
$$
here we need that $f(c) > 0$. And for $x > c$ is
$$
 g(x) \le \frac{c^{-k}f(c)}{x^{1-k}} \implies \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0 \, .
$$
It follows that  $g(x^*) = 1$ for some $x^* > 0 $, i.e. $f(x^*) = x^*$.
Now we show that the fixed point is unique. Assume that $0< a < b$ with $f(a) = a$ and $f(b) = b$. Then
$$
 a^{1-k} =  a^{-k}f(a) \ge b^{-k}f(b) = b^{1-k} 
\implies a \ge b
$$
is a contradiction.
Remark: The proof shows that only the upper bound for $f'$ is needed: It suffices to assume that $x f'(x) \le k f(x)$ for all $x > 0$, and $f(c) > 0$ for some $c > 0$.

This argument uses what appears to be a crucial assumption ( $0\leq k <1$). (+1)

@Hey: The “upper estimate” $ x f'(x) \leq k f(x)$ suggests to compare $f$ with the solution of the differential equation $ x f'(x) = k f(x)$, and that is $x^k$.

@Hey: This approach is similar to solutions of the differential inequality $f'(x) \le f(x)$ (see e.g. here) where you consider $e^{-x} f(x)$ because $e^x$ is the solution of $f'(x) = f(x)$.

@MartinR Thank you! Sorry for deleting my comment I thought it was stupid)
P.S the comment I deleted: how can I guess to work with $x^{-k}f(x)$

The assumption implies
$$(\log f(x))'\le k(\log x)'$$ Therefore the function $h(x):=\log f(x)-k\log x$ is nonincreasing on all intervals, where $f(x)>0.$
First we are going to show that if $f$ is not zero identically, then $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0.$
Assume $f(x_0)>0$ for some $x_0.$ Let $(a,b)$ be the largest interval containing $x_0$ such that $f(x)>0$ for $a<x<b.$ If $a>0,$ then $f(a)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+}h(x)=-\infty,$ which is impossible as $h$ is nonincreasing. Thus $f(x)>0$ for $0<x\le x_0.$  Assume $b<\infty.$ Then $f(b)=0.$ We  have
$${|f'(x)|\over f(x)}\le {k\over x}\le {2k\over b},\ {b\over 2}\le x<b\quad (*)$$  When $x\to b^-$ then $f(x)\to 0^+.$ Hence  $-\log f(x)\to \infty,$  when $x\to b^-.$ Therefore  the derivative $$(-\log f(x))'=-{f'(x)\over f(x)},\quad {b\over 2}\le x<b$$ cannot be bounded. We get a contradiction in view of $(*).$ Thus $b=\infty,$ i.e. $f(x)>0$ for $x\ge x_0.$
Assume $f(x)$ does not have a fixed point. Then
$f(x)\neq x$ for all $x>0.$ Thus

$ f(x)> x$ for all $x>0$
$ f(x)< x$ for all $x>0$

By 1. we have
$$ h(x)=\log f(x)-k\log x>(1-k)\log x,\quad x>0$$ The LHS is nonincreasing, while RHS is increasing to $\infty$ when $x\to\infty.$ This leads to a contradiction.
In the case 2, we get
$$  h(x)=\log f(x)-k\log x<(1-k)\log x,\quad 0<x<x_0$$ The limit of RHS when $x\to 0^+$ is equal $-\infty.$ This is impossible as $h(x)$ is nonincreasing.
Concerning the uniqueness of the fixed point, assume $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=b$ for $a<b.$ In particular $f(x)>0$ for $0<x<b.$ We get $h(a)=(1-k)\log a$ and $h(b)=(1-k)\log b.$ By IMV there is $a<c<b$ such that $$h'(c)={1-k\over c}$$ This leads to a contradiction as $h'(c)\le 0.$
Remark In the first part on the positivity of $f,$ the assumption $k<1$ is not essential. Any positive $k$ suffices. In the second part the assumption $0<k<1$ is essential but only one inequality, namely $xf'(x)\le kf(x)$ has been used.

@Martin R The proof is now fixed. It is hard to resist from  dividing by $f(x)$ when $f'(x)$ is on the other side.

Yes, your proof is fine now (already voted :) – My approach was inspired by inequalities like $f'(x) \le f(x)$ where one can consider $e^{-x} f(x)$ instead of dividing by $f(x)$.

“$f(x_0) > 0$ implies $f(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$” can alternatively be concluded  from the facts that $x^{-k} f(x)$ is decreasing and $x^k f(x)$ is increasing.
